# Using include() within ob_start()

Tags: php

Need a bit of PHP help here, the included content is appearing as '1' which means that its true but need it's contents to appear and im unsure why it isn't. Here is a shortened version of a function:

```
public function content {
    $website->content = 'Some content here. ';
    ob_start();
    include('myfile.php');
    $file_content = ob_end_clean();
    $website->content .= $file_content;
    $website->content .= ' Some more content here.';
     echo $website->content;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Some content here 
1 
Some more content here
```

When I need it to output:

```
Some content here
'Included file content here'
Some more content here
```

Any idea's how I can fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `ob_get_clean()` instead of `ob_end_clean()`.

Both clear the current buffer but `ob_end_clean()` returns a boolean, whereas `ob_get_clean()` returns the contents of the current buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `ob_end_clean` modify your existing code into something similar to the below

```
ob_start();

include('myfile.php');

$file_content = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean ();
```

The reason I'm not voting for `ob_get_clean` is because I've had times when other developers get confused regarding what is really going on, the function name doesn't really state that the output buffering will end after it's call.

I think that function will be prone to further bugs, therefor using `ob_start`/`ob_end_clean` is easier to comprehend and better for future code maintenance.

The trade off between one extra line of code but easier code to understand is well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean), not [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_end_clean).  The former returns a string of the output buffer and empties it, while the latter just does the emptying and returns a bool.