# Is it possible to use php tags inside ob_start buffer?

Tags: php, eval, echo, ob-start

I am trying to make complex template library. The thing is that I am holding my own syntax and php inside the same file as mixed.

1. First my syntax is parsed and reformatted. Output is usual html + php as string. I don't want to make cache file but use string containing the "middle" template instead.
2. On this template (string containing php tags and html) the php operations should be executed.

MyComplexTemplate(my syntax + php) =parse=> Template(HTML+PHP) =exec php=> Result(HTML)

For 2. I am trying to use ob_start() with echo, but everything inside php tags gets vanished.

For example:

```php
<?php
  $asd = "123";
  ob_start();
  echo "<div><?php echo $asd; ?></div>"; // Middle template
  $result = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  echo $result;
?>
```

The result should be "<div>123</div>". At the moment I get only div tags.

This is just a simple example. My template will contain all kind of php operations inside php tags.

Is this kind of operation possible somehow?

#### UPDATE

Template i.e.: (template.php)

```
.mySyntax (...) and so on
  <?php foreach($asd as $data): ?>
  <div><?php echo $data ?></div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  .mySyntax
    some text
```

Parsing template with MySyntaxParser and executing php after that, which is left untouched:

```
<?php
  $t = new MySyntaxParser("template.php"); // My parser. Converts mySyntax to html.
  $asd = array("test1", "test2");

  ob_start();
  echo $t->parse(); // Should execute php code inside the string;
  $result = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  echo $result;
?>
```

#### UPDATE

I want to achieve allmost exact thing like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309805/878435) but require_once should somehow come from string:

## **SOLUTION**

Actually the solution is in this topic [PHP: Equivalent of include using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184628/php-difference-include-eval) . eval must be used with pre and postpadded with php tags.

Also you should check out [**THIS**](http://www.intechgrity.com/understanding-php-eval-function-and-usage-do-more-than-just-evaluating/) blogpost.

Like here:

```
<?php
  $asd = "123";
  ob_start();
  eval ('?>
    <?php foreach(array("asd", "asx123") as $data): ?>
    <div><?php echo $data ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php;');
  ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: PHP tags don't nest, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I can not imagine the advantage of doing as you did. What I know is that is incredibly ugly...

Comment: The example was informal. My created class can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/30kgBbwy).

Answer (score 2):

Well, what I see in my source is `<div><?php echo 123; ?></div>`, which is exactly what you would expect. The browser treats `<?php echo 123; ?>` as a single tag, (which it doesn't know) and ignores it.

The simpler solution would be to use

```
echo "<div>$asd</div>";
```

If you want some sort of templating engine, I suggest you look at already made ones and see how they work. Have a special look about MVC and MVC frameworks.

Comment: It's good point to view some already made library. I'm trying to do exacly the same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8510592/878435). But I want to get include data from string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP tags. Just:

```
echo "<div>$asd</div>"; // Middle template
```

Comment: The thing is that in my template I have php tags. I need to use. ie. <?php for(...): ?> some html <?php endfor; ?>

Comment: Then the code you posted is not useful, as it doesn't show the actual way you use a template file. You likely just need to `include()` the template file in the output buffering, which will appropriately render the PHP tags. You can't use `<?php ?>` tags within an echo statement.

Comment: I updated the example. Maybe it gives a better view what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $asd = "123";
  ob_start();
?>

  <div><?php echo $asd; ?></div>
  <div><?php include('mytemplate.php'); ?></div>

[...] // some stuff here

<?php
  $result = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: This way it works yes. But I want that the template would come from string.